# Mac OS X Terminal.app reconnect

Tags: macos, terminal.app, connection

When I'm connection to a remote server via ssh inside a Terminal window, and I put the computer to sleep, when I come back the connection is of course interrupted. The problem is there seems to be no way to resurrect the window and its associated local bash prompt. All I really care about is re-using the Terminal window. I don't want to have to do command+N which opens a tiny window, and have to resize it, and position it on the screen, etc. Shouldn't there be some way to use the same window and local shell? I would kind of expect a sleep action to cause the ssh program to drop back to a local bash prompt, so I don't understand why the window seems to be completely dead.

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/19634/how-to-reconnect-to-a-disconnected-ssh-session for a number of solutions and workarounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> to terminate a SSH session.

(<kbd>~</kbd> is `ssh`'s escape character, and it only works after a new-line.)

Answer (score 4):

What happens if you use Ctrl-C?  The other option would be to create a new tab, rather than a new window by using Command-T instead of Command-N.  And another option on top of that would be to open a new tab, use the killall command to force SSH to end, and then close the new tab.

Comment: `killall ssh` is my usual fix for this.

Comment: ctrl+c didn't fix it. Or maybe it did, but took awhile. In any case, it appears killing it does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

wait a few minutes and you'll get the prompt back.
If you don't want to wait, you can copy and paste the screen to a text file, open a new terminal tab/window and cat the file. (You'll lose the colours though)